# I dropped a table in Oracle, how can I retrieve it from the undo tablespace?

Tags: sql, oracle, undo, flashback, sql-drop

I accidentally dropped a fairly large table -- recycling bin is not enabled. I'm fairly certain the data still exists in the UNDO tablespace, but I'm not sure how to get it out. I recreated the table exactly as it was before it was dropped -- the structure is exactly the same. However, when I attempt to flashback the table, I get this error:

```
flashback table tablex to timestamp (systimestamp - interval '120' minute);
Error: 01466
DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-01466: unable to read data - table definition has changed
```

Any idea how I can overcome this error? From all of the searching I've done, it seems as if it believes the table is not structurally the same as when it was dropped.

Comment: Hm, I didn't rollback because I thought dropping a table couldn't actually be undone by a rollback. I thought only DML operations like insert and update could be rolled back?

Comment: FLASHBACK TABLE doesn't require the recyling bin when using the flashback to timestamp functionality. If you're using that, it checks in the UNDO tablespace, as far as I know (I could be wrong here).

Comment: If recycle bin is not enabled, and you confirmed it by seeing `off` in the `value` column in the result of `show parameter recyclebin`, then really no easy way to bring the table back without to do a point-in-time recovery of database or a talespace. You also could try to restore and recover dropped table by using `LogMiner` but it probably would take much more time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not recreate the table by yourself - it will be recreated for you by Oracle when you Flashback it, I recommend the following article: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/flashback-10g.php#flashback_table

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE flashback_table_test (
  id NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_flashback_table_test PRIMARY KEY
);

DROP TABLE flashback_table_test;
FLASHBACK TABLE flashback_table_test TO BEFORE DROP;
```

I think you will need to flash it back using some SCN number prior to the number when you manually recreated the table.